# Dynamically reordering DIV elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I recently started studying html, css and javascript since I'm quite interested in being able to create my own news website and I realized that I don't really know how to accomplish the following thing :

I want my website's homepage to have 10 div blocks and every one of them to have a headline with hyperlink to the corresponding html page. However, when I add a new div, I want the bottom div block disappear so it can make room for the newest div that's gonna be on top.

To be quite honest I have no idea what I need to study to accomplish this. Here's an image depicting what I want to accomplish.

[image]

Can you throw me a brief explanation or some keywords for me to google in order to understand how to do that?

Comment: Are going to be adding new div dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean moving it to a different page?

Comment: What you're looking is typical for a blog. You should consider ready made blogging solutions, such as wordpress or typepad.

Comment: OP, your question is really a bit broad. You need to try and put effort into explaining clearly exactly what you want help with in order to get good answers from the community. Try and format your question so that it illustrates what you have done so far and specifically what you have a problem with. A very broad question is likely to attract only very broad answers and is unlikely to help you or anyone else.

Comment: Made post more readable, in-lined image for usability , removed mysql tag, different title

Comment: Put the 10 divs inside another div.Use jquery to find the children of the container div, then use it to remove the last one, and then use it to insert a new one. Basically, use jquery -- it'll make this a lot easier. Start by looking at the children() method (https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a tricky question without knowing precisely how you want the items (the div elements you mentioned) to be added.

If you are adding these items to the set dynamically (without reloading the entire page), then you may want to use the *overflow* property of the container of these items. This way, you can keep the items that were already in the set from disappearing as someone is about to visit them.

Otherwise, if you plan on only loading the latest items in your database when the page is visited, you will simply have to use the correct queries to return only the correct amount (the amount that fits in your "set") of most recent data from your database.

I should probably mention that building this website from the ground up without any help will be quite the challenge for a beginner. Especially since you will have to do all of the back-end work as well to set up your database. I'd advise seeking help from someone with experience in this area if you can, because it wouldn't be much fun to start off in the wrong direction and have to completely restart!